# Extend div to right of page without wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I think the solution I need is to extend the wrapper div to the right of the page without wrapping. If I set the width to `width: 100vw` or `width: 100%`, all of the content within the div move below all the other content.

looks kinda weird but here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8u3Lzjxw/

what happens if you set `width` to `100%` or `100vh`
[image]

wrapper should extend to cover all highlighted in green. The height is not a problem as it's not being interfered with.

[image]

Relevant HTML:

```html
    <div class="active-sockets">
        <h1 class="active">Active Sockets</h1>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="socket">
                <h2 class="socket-name">Lorem Ispum</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;   
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.socket {
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    margin: .2em;
    padding: .8em;
    border-top-left-radius: .5em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .5em;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.active-sockets {
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;
    height: 100vh;
}

.active {
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em;
    border-top-left-radius: .25em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .25em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to structure a page like this.  To keep inline with what you have, there are a couple CSS properties that need to change in your fiddle.

Since the side-bar has a width of 2em, then the margin of the active sockets needs to be at least 3em.  And also, if you want it to snap to the top, then remove the top margin.  This is what the style will look like:

```
.active-sockets {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 3em;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

you also want to take away the padding of the side bar:

```
.side-bar {
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    padding: 0;
    width: 2em;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```